# How to put text below photo

Tags: php, image

I want add text just below the picture but I don't know how to do it.

[image: Example]

```
<?php


include "includes/connexio_web.php";
obrirConnexioBD();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Llistat_vies";
$sth = $conn->query($sql);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"; ?> 
        <img src="<?php echo $row["photo"]; ?>" height="200" width="200"><?php echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>"; echo $row["text"]; echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Change your <tr> to <tr style='display:flex'> ?

Comment: Maybe put it in a new row? `echo "<tr><td>"; echo $row["text"]; echo "</td></tr>";`.  Or put it in the same `<td>` as the image with a `<br>` before it.

Comment: Thanks for the help but doesnt work.

Comment: if i use  br image and text go below and i want only the text below.

Comment: Make sure your `<td>`s are all closed. And where is the table that those rows and cells are supposed to be in?

Comment: @Dave if it resolve your request, please mark it as answered.

Comment: Wrong person @Vidal. I'm not the one with the issue.

Comment: GUILLEM NAVALON BABIA if it resolve your request please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Here your code updated.

```
<?php

   include "includes/connexio_web.php";
        obrirConnexioBD();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Llistat_vies";
        $sth = $conn->query($sql);
     $table= "<table>";
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sth)){
       $table= "<tr>
          <td align='center'> 
            <img src=".$row["photo"] ." height='200' width='200'> <br>
            $row["text"]
          </td>
       </tr>";

    }

print $table . "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**try these new HTML5 tags**: 
`<figure>` and `<figcaption>`

Put your image and text inside these tags like this:

```
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td>"; ?> 
    <figure>
    <img src="<?php echo $row["photo"]; ?>" height="200" width="200">
    <figcaption>
    <?php  echo $row["text"];
   echo "</figcaption>";
   echo "</figure>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am pretending that your `<table>` and `<tr>` are outside of the loop.

```
<table>
<tr>

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {

        echo "<td>";
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        ?>
          <img src="<?php echo $row["photo"]; ?>" height="200" width="200">
        <?php
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $row["text"];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        echo "</td>";
    }
</tr>
</table>
```

I put tables within the table an inside of a `<td>` so that they would be next to each other.

I don't know if this is the best way but it was similar to what you were doing and it worked for me. I hope this helps.